# How to insert an array into object in React

Tags: reactjs

How to insert an array into object dynamically.

I am using multiselect. Depending on my selected value I want to insert new object with updated selected value with previous one.

I do not want to change the `id` only `type` should change.

```
let newList = [];
    handleOnRowChange = (value) => {
    const value = ['En', 'Ta', 'Fr'];
    const existingListIdObj = {rowIndex: 0, id: '8538', type: En}
        const newObj = {
            ...existingListIdObj,
            id: existingListIdObj.id,
            type: value    
          };
    }
newList.push(newObj);
newList.push(existingListIdObj);


    onChange={(e) =>
      this.handleOnRowChange(
        e.target.value
      )
    }

Expected Result:

    {rowIndex: 0, id: '8538', type: En} 
    {rowIndex: 1, id: '8538', type: Ta} 
    {rowIndex: 2, id: '8538', type: Fr}
```

Comment: In your "expected result", do you want to create 3 new objects or are you changing a single object three times?

Comment: Please explain better the problem, I don't understand what you want. Besides, you are overriding the value argument by defining a new const

Comment: I am using multiselect. Depending on my selected value I want to insert new object with updated selected value with previous one.

Comment: @RashmiUI It sounds like you need to show more code to illustrate what you are trying to do. You should also include some screenshots of the UI you are trying to create and explain the user interactions.